# How to validate Email address using Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm doing a two step sign up process. First email, then password.

I'd like to validate if the email is not in use or badly formatted first. If it's ok, then show the password form.

Right now I can't find a good way to verify if the email is used.

I'd expect something like this:

```
 firebaseAuth.validateEmailAddress(email)
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? It would make it very easy for someone to retrieve the list of emails of all your users.

Comment: that'll be on you to handle , Firebase doesn't expose validation methods in their api , they just verify ... I would try passing a poorly formatted email and see what error you get .

Comment: @pzp can you tell me more about that? I don't understand how would that allow somebody to retrieve the list of emails.

Comment: @bernatfortet I could simply try email addresses brute force style on the email sign in page, and see which ones take me to the password page. If I get to the password page I know that email address belongs to some user.

Comment: I guess you now have an answer so how did you solve this problem @bernatfortet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if an email is in use by checking if fetchProvidersForEmail returns an empty array.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#fetchProvidersForEmail

Comment: This method no longer exists in 2022

Comment: use fetchSignInMethodsForEmail instead https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#fetchsigninmethodsforemail